# Remove enemy when bullet hits them

Tags: java, 2d, processing

```
class Bullet {
  float bulletX, bulletY;
  float angle;
  int x; 
  int y;
  int score;  // add a score variable
  static final float BULLET_SPEED = 5;  // define a constant for the bullet's speed



  Bullet(float x, float y, float angle) {
    this.bulletX = x;
    this.bulletY = y;
    this.angle = angle;
  }


  // Updates the position of the bullet based on its angle and speed.
  void update() {
    bulletX += cos(angle) * BULLET_SPEED;
    bulletY += sin(angle) * BULLET_SPEED;
  }


  // Draws the bullet image on the screen.

  void show() {
    drawBullet();
  }


  // Draws the bullet image on the screen.

  void drawBullet() {
    image(Bulletimg, bulletX, bulletY);
    Bulletimg.resize(30, 30);
    
    
    
  }


  //Returns true if the bullet is off screen, false otherwise.

  boolean offScreen() {
    return bulletX < 0 || bulletX > width || bulletY < 0 || bulletY > height;
  }


  //Checks if the bullet hits the enemy, and updates the score and enemy position accordingly.
  // check for collision

  void checkCollision(Enemy e) {
    float distance = dist(bulletX, bulletY, e.x, e.y);
    if (distance < e.x / 2) { 
     // assuming enemy.size is the radius of the
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing around the  check collision(enemy e) block and I'm not sure how i would go about removing an enemy object and also updating my score. i've tried messing about with the draw(); method but i cant seem to figure it out without breaking my entire game. any help with this class would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use/create some attribute in your Enemy object to know/check if is alive or death.

For example in your check collision you can add

```
if (distance < e.x / 2) { 
 // assuming enemy.size is the radius of the
 e.alive = false 
}
```

Edit: I dont know how your manage the Enemy object and if it can be modified directly in the check collision method if this is not possible then you need to find a way to have access inside the method or use a return and manage that return outside.